# Digital Goods Express Checkout with Paypal Rest API

Tags: python, api, rest, paypal

I'm using Paypal's REST API on Python through [rest-api-sdk-python](https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-python/tree/master/paypalrestsdk). I'm a bit confused though as to what the whole [Digital Goods for Express Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/digital-goods/IntroducingExpressCheckoutDG/) translates to in the REST API. I think I am using express checkout, as that's cmd used in the generated URL, but I just want to confirmed that it's "Digital Goods".

Comment: I still haven't found a solution for this missing, have you? The only workaround is to insert a fake address... :-(

Comment: Its 2020 now, and I still have not seen any movement in the REST API to properly support the NVP `L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMCATEGORY0=Digital` method. I mean, really... what in how can this be difficult to add...